# When submitting a power bi custom visual for certification we got 1200.1.1 Code Repository error?

Tags: powerbi

Here is the error we received from Microsoft Power BI Custom Visuals Team.

> Source Code 
>   1200.1.1  Code Repository 
>   The validation team was unable to download the source code from the provided location.
>   There is no certification branch available.
>   Please ensure the source code is available for review and re-submit your offer.

What needs to be done for the above message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [Code repository requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/power-bi-custom-visuals-certified#code-repository-requirements):

> Although you don't have to publicly share your code in GitHub, the code repository has to be available for a review by the Power BI team. The best way to do this, is by providing the source code (JavaScript or TypeScript) in GitHub.
>
> The repository must contain the following:
>
> - Code for only one Power BI visual. It can't contain code for multiple Power BI visuals, or unrelated code.
> - A branch named **certification** (lowercase required). The source code in this branch has to match the submitted package. This code can only be updated during the next submission process, if you're resubmitting your Power BI visual.

And in the message returned from the certification team:

> Source Code 1200.1.1 Code Repository The validation team was unable to download the source code from the provided location. **There is no certification branch available.** Please ensure the source code is available for review and re-submit your offer.

You must make a branch named `certification`.

For more information, you can review [Get a Power BI visual certified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/power-bi-custom-visuals-certified) article.